# How to consume third party .flow files?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

I'm working on adding [flow](https://flow.org/en/) to a React.js app. I've used [flow-typed](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed) to add several packages, which seems to be working.

This issue is that I'm using the [Material-UI beta](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui). They don't have a repo in flow-typed, but they do provide `Component.js.flow` files.

However, I'm getting this error:

```
Error: src/NotFound/NotFound.js:6
  6: import Button from 'material-ui/Button'
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ material-ui/Button. Required module not found

Error: src/NotFound/NotFound.js:8
  8: import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles'
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ material-ui/styles. Required module not found
```

My `.flowconfig`:

```
[ignore]
<PROJECT_ROOT>/node_modules/.*
<PROJECT_ROOT>/build/.*
<PROJECT_ROOT>/scripts/.*
<PROJECT_ROOT>/coverage/.*
<PROJECT_ROOT>/config/.*
.*\.test\.js

[include]

[libs]
<PROJECT_ROOT>/flow-typed/.*

[lints]

[options]
emoji=true
```

I've tried several solutions in support forums, but I'm still not understanding how to wire this up.

Important package versions:

```
react@15.5.4
material-ui@1.0.0-beta.8
flow-bin@0.54.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flow doesn't think `material-ui` exists because you're explicitly ignoring all files within `node_modules` in your `.flowconfig`. Remove the first line under `[ignore]` (`<PROJECT_ROOT>/node_modules/.*`) and you should be good to go.

Note that some other libraries may cause flow issues. You should just ignore those selectively, rather than blanket ignore all 3rd party libs.

Comment: Ahh, thank you! That makes sense now.

It's much more verbose, but this is what my updated `.flowconfig` [looks like now](https://gist.github.com/zachwolf/16ec6d728d83680fb19c7c31f17d004b).

(linked due to character limit)

Comment: Follow up question: I'm now not getting errors, but it doesn't seem like the files are getting used still. If I import a component and purposefully pass a wrong prop, flow still reports no errors. Any ideas what could be going wrong?